# Django throws NoReverseMatch error when the urlconf is not empty?

Tags: django, django-urls

In my main urlconf, I'm including an app's urlconf:

```
url(r"^items/$", include("items.urls")),
```

In `items/urls.py` I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r"^profile/", ProfileView.as_view(), name="accounts_profile"),
    url(r"^$", DashboardView.as_view(), name="items_home"),
)
```

The problem is that no matter what I enter to urlconf -- except for `r"^$"` -- I'm getting a `NoReverseMatch` error in the template calling one of these urlconfs via e.g. `{% url accounts_profile %}`. I've tried with different views from different apps, different urlconf names etc, but no luck. Any ideas?

I'm using Django 1.3.1, FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it -- the problem was with the `$` sign in the import statement above, which signified the end of the line. Feeling so silly. :-/

Comment: just about to click 'post your answer' =p .  you may also want to use r"^profile/$"